# Calculating geo coordinates along a trajectory

Tags: php, algorithm, geocode

I am looking for an algorithm (php would be most ideal) that can, given two sets of coordinates (start and end), calculate the geographical coordinates along that path at given intervals (say every mile). Note that I am not looking for something like Bresenham's algorithm - I want the exact coordinates along the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the latitude/longitude of a point at a given distance along a [great circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatCircle.html) passing through your start- and end-point.  You'll find the formulae worked out [**here**](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Intermediate), which you should be able to adapt to your use case.

Comment: I adapted the calculations to my code - the page offers great circle formulas as well as rhumb line. I should mention that for local distances (I was testing 30 mile radius) the great circle formula is so far off it's useless (it works for the lax/jfk example they use but is way off for smaller distances). The rhumb line algorithm is spot on for both the example as well as shorter distances.